# Skinny 141lbs 5'10" with bad posture and belly pouch

Tags: training, bellyfat, posture

Last month i've noticed how my belly is getting bigger and it's just adding to my body problems.

Is there something i can do to correct/fix my posture and belly at home or is going to the gym inevitable ?  What kind of exercises should I focus on and what not to ? Also I don't count my calories intake but i think i'm slightly underweight even if I eat normally.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You look like you have an anterior pelvic tilt (weak abs, hamstrings and glutes with tight over-active lower back and  and hip flexors)  and rounded back (weak rhomboids and lower traps with tight over-active pecs)

[APT](https://www.fixflatfeet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/APTcomponents.jpg)

[Rounded shoulders](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52d56225e4b0e9203b2a6579/t/584ebdbcd2b8572e19536d31/1481555393326/)

Not a comprehensive list at all, but these exercises should do some good

Cat cow (will stretch some problematic areas): https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOj76wV2WfPvwk3LlWoEMDjcBeWZ93YIi

Shoulders:

YTWL: https://youtu.be/3MxHX9j15BU

Rows: https://www.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/wiki/exercises/row

APT:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/3q6i3b/my_progress_with_apt_anterior_pelvic_tilt/

Plank (abs): https://youtu.be/kL_NJAkCQBg

Hollow hold (abs): https://youtu.be/LlDNef_Ztsc

Glute bridge: https://youtu.be/O9j_DU_4KXs

Lunge stretch